# How can I copy a database in Azure SQL Server to Azure SQL Managed Instance in different Azure Subscription

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-sql-managed-instance

I created an Azure SQL managed instance using terraform in Azure Subscription A.

I am trying to copy the databases in an existing Azure SQL Server in Subscription B to the SQL Managed Instances I created in Subscription A.

How can I go about this?  I cannot find any resource that addresses a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a direct copy method that would cover that combination, but could you not export to bacpac (stored as a blob in a storage account or if small enough for your link to deal with quickly as a local file) then import to the target location? Use either SSMS or the appropriate command line tools.